# Adding a variable in Content disposition response file name-python/django

Tags: python, django, string, download, django-views

I am looking to add a a variable into the file name section of my below python code so that the downloaded file's name will change based on a user's input upon download.

So instead of "Data.xlsx" it would include my variable (based on user input) + "Data.xlsx". I saw a similar question but based in PHP and couldn't figure out how to adapt it to python.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "Data.xlsx"'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{}"'.format(filename)
```

Using [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % filename
```

or concatenating strings:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "' + filename + '"'
```

Comment: or fstring: 

    `response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename= {filename}'`